# css - @media isn't working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

***Okay, I found a solution: with `@media` I'm accessing the image's width and the bar separately and it's working but is there any shorter way codewise?***

I searched the internet for a solution but none of what I found helped me so far.

I'm trying to make my header to be responsive to the browser's width but it isn't working.

I tried to make just the image responsive or just the top bar but nothing works...

Any ideas?

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#החשבון שלי">החשבון שלי</a></li>
        <li><a href="#המתכונים שלי">המתכונים שלי</a></li>
        <li><a href="#אודות">אודות</a></li>
        <li class="last-btn"><a href="#צרו קשר">צרו קשר</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <a href="#banner"><img src="Images\maadanot_winter_banners.jpg" alt="אפייה חורפית"/></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

and this is the css:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

.top-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #404040;
    padding: 12px;
}

.nav-container {
    width: 68%;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #404040;
    display: table;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar li {
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
    .header {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.banner {
    margin-top: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `width: 100%` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it into:

```
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
    .header {
        width: 100vw; /* viewport width */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want, but to get your image span the whole width in all sizes, you can add this rule:

```
.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will size the image *within*  its container (which has 100% width, so eventually the image will span the width).

BTW: `.banner` is a DIV that will be 100% wide anyway, so you actually can erase the 100% width for `.banner`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 12px;
}

.nav-container {
  width: 68%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #404040;
  display: table;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar li {
  display: table-cell;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 85px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .header {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.banner {
  margin-top: 33px;
}
.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#החשבון שלי">החשבון שלי</a></li>
        <li><a href="#המתכונים שלי">המתכונים שלי</a></li>
        <li><a href="#אודות">אודות</a></li>
        <li class="last-btn"><a href="#צרו קשר">צרו קשר</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1200x90/fa0" alt="אפייה חורפית" /></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Someone else mentioned it too. originally it was set to 100%, I changed it just to try and by mistake posted it here.

I do have the 'meta' code but it still isn't working...

Comment: Note: I changed my answer completely after your comment - see above

Answer (score 0):

device-width is not correct value for width.
Use : <
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width, which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%.

The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

Comment: I changed it to 'device-width' just for trying, originally it was set to 100%, I'll edit it now

Answer (score 0):

When you are working om Media Queries, You have to need change inherit property if you declare cascaded down.If you have set Backgruond images on the body, there is need a queries to cancel background images.

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.